# free $\mathbb Z$-module of rank $2$

Tags: modules

Let $M$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$ and $p$ be a prime. Determine the number of submodules $N$ of $M$ such that $M/N \cong \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$.

The answer may be $2$, but I cannot find a proof.

Comment: Since $p$ is prime, saying $M/N \cong {\mathbf Z}/p{\mathbf Z}$ is the same as saying $N$ has index $p$ in $M$. If $N \subset M$ has index $p$ then $p(M/N)$ is 0, so $pM \subset N$. Thus $pM \subset N \subset M$, so counting such $N$ is the same as counting index $p$ subgroups of $M/pM \cong ({\mathbf Z}/p{\mathbf Z})^2$, which is now a linear algebra problem. In a similar way, the index $d$ submodules of $M$ are in bijection with the index $d$ subgroups of $({\mathbf Z}/d{\mathbf Z})^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a minimal submodule $K$ such that $M/K$ is of exponent $p$, and this is clearly $K = p M$.

So the question reduces to counting the submodules $N/K$ of $M/K$ such that $(M/K)/(N/K) \cong M/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $M / K \cong \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$, a vector space of dimension two over the field $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$, this number is readily seen to be $p+1$.